# Python code not showing correct day of week in Indian Time Zone

Tags: python, datetime, dayofweek, pytz

Hi I am working with date time and timezone in Python. My code is working perfectly. Only this is not showing the correct day of week in Indian time zone. If I run this code from my local machine all is ok. But if I host the code in other time zone it is not showing correct day of week in Indian time zone. My code is given below.

```
import pytz
import datetime

start_time = '09:15'
end_time = '15:45'

ist = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')

ind_time = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata")).strftime('%H:%M')
print(ind_time)

current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
print(current_time)

day_of_week = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()
print(day_of_week)

if ind_time > start_time and ind_time < end_time and day_of_week <5:
               print("Hallo World")

if ind_time > end_time:
               pass # to return nothing
```

Can anyone help me to correct this code?

Comment: Did you mean to take `.weekday()` of `datetime.datetime.today()` or of `ind_time`?

Comment: More generally, try the [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) guide?

Answer (score 0):

You probably intended to do:

```
day_of_week = ind_time.weekday()
print(day_of_week)
```

Comment: I want to take weekday() of ind_time. I tried your code but getting error day_of_week = ind_time.weekday()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'weekday'

Comment: I solved this using `ind_date = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata"))
print(ind_date)

day_of_week = ind_date.weekday()
print(day_of_week)`

Comment: That's the one!